# Prevent user from clicking somewhere else while ajax loading a page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a web application for PCs and tablets using jQuery Mobile.

And I'm using Ajax navigation feature of jQuery Mobile.

So, if user clicks on a link, loading spinner shows. But while JQM is trying to load that page, user may click on another link. In this case, after completely loading the first page, JQM loads the second page and then goes to the second page.

**Now, I want to disable everything while ajax navigation is working.** Everything means, No other link should be clicked, no other javascript `click` function should be called, no scrolling can be possible, and...

Also there should be a timeout for each ajax navigation.

How to do this?

Comment: May be I should put a transparent overlay on the screen, but How? Where?

Comment: Exactly what you say. This is a nifty plugin to do just that... http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: @VDP But how to replace jQuery Mobile default loading spinner with this plugin?

Comment: Can we detect when loading spinner shows and hides? if so, we can simply put a `div` with `position:absolute` over the page...

Comment: You can prevent that loading message ([showLoadMsg:false](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html)). Just prevent the message and listen for the 'pagebeforeload' to set your div over the page. (maybe you have to listen for click events on the div and prevent bubbling down too)

Answer (score 1):

jQM has a few different events that fire when a new page has finished loading into the DOM. Why not temporarily deactivate all links, once a link has been clicked, until the transition has finished?

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
        return false;
    }); 
    $(document).bind('pagechange', function() { 
        $('body').off('click', 'a'); 
    }); 
});
```

I used the `pagechange` event above, but there are a few other events that might work better for your purposes. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: First, there are some buttons that not use `<a>` tags, they are handling by javascript `click` event. And next, this may be too slow, especially on Tablets... (for example, Javascript engine of Mobile Safari is too slow)